# Express App Test Suite with Supertest Breaks when switching from MemoryStore to express-mysql-session

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, express-session, supertest

I have an Express app that has a test suite using Jest.

When I use the default memory session storage, all my tests work fine. When I upgraded to `express-mysql-session` for session storage, a bunch of the tests broke. However, with manual testing everything is still working as designed. This makes me think the problem is somewhere with how I have implemented the `supertest` call.

I inserted a bunch of `console.log` calls everywhere and I've narrowed the problem down to when I call the `req.login` function in my route (simplified example code):

The test looks something like this:

```js
const request = require('supertest')

beforeAll(async () => {
    // Make the connection using my database handler
    db.connect()
})

test('Sets a cookie and redirects to / after logging in.', async () => {
    // This is a synchronous function that just returns an object with keys `id` and `password`
    const newCredentials = newValidUserCredentials() 
    // An asynchronous function that creates this user in the database for testing
    await processNewUserRegistrationData(newCredentials)

    const agent = request.agent(app)

    await agent
        .post('/login')
        .send(newCredentials)
        .expect(302)
        .expect('set-cookie', /sessionID=/)
        .expect('Location', '/')
        .then(async (resp) => {
            // Shows the 'set-cookie' field when using MemoryStore, but when using MySQLStore it never even console.logs
            console.log(resp.header) 
            // It is important to access the cookie here so I can call `agent` again in tests that require authentication
        })

})

afterAll(async () => {
    // Close the connection using my database handler
    db.close()
})
```

The route is setup something like this:

```js
loginRouter.post(
    '/',
    someMiddleware(req, res, next),
    async function authenticateMiddleware(req, res, next) {
        await passport.authenticate('local', async (err, user, errorMessage) => {
            if (errorMessage) {
                // Do some error event logging stuff
                // ...
                return res.render('pages/login', {
                    failureMessage:
                        'Unable to authenticate with that email and password combination'
                })
            }
            console.log('SUCCESSFULLY AUTHENTICATED:', user)

            // There is an existing user, and this user has successfully authenticated. Log them in.
            console.log('LOGGING IN USER')
            req.login(user, (error) => {
                console.log('OPERATING INSIDE THE LOGIN CALLBACK FUNCTION NOW...')
                // Do some event logging stuff
                // ...
                return next()
            })
        })(req, res, next)
    },
    moreMiddleware(req, res, next),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log('FINAL REQUEST COOKIE IN HEADER:', req.headers.cookie)
        res.redirect('/')
    }
)
```

The `app.js` has a session store configuration like this.

```js
// ...
app.use(
    session({
        store: new MySQLStore({
            host: config.EXPRESS_HOST,
            port: config.DATABASE_PORT,
            user: config.DATABASE_USER,
            password: config.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            database: config.DATABASE_NAME,
            createDatabaseTable: false,
            clearExpired: true,
            checkExpirationInterval: 900 * 1000,
            schema: {
                tableName: 'SESSIONS',
                columnNames: {
                    session_id: 'SESSION_ID',
                    expires: 'EXPIRES',
                    data: 'DATA'
                }
            }
        }),
        name: 'sessionID',
        secret: config.EXPRESS_SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        rolling: true,
        cookie: {
            secure: false, // Dev environments on 'localhost' run on http so secure won't work. Set to true on the production server
            httpOnly: true,
            domain: config.EXPRESS_HOST,
            maxAge: config.EXPRESS_SESSION_LIMIT_DAYS * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        }
    })
    // ...
// ...
```

Commenting out the `store` key reverts Express to using the MemoryStore method and the test works again with all `console.log` statements outputting as expected.

When the `MySQLStore` store is used during the test, it console logs all the way up to `LOGGING IN USER`, then nothing. The test then fails with the error

> thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
> Add a timeout value to this test to increase the timeout, if this is a long-running test. See [https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout."](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testname-fn-timeout.%22)

as well as telling me

> A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.

What is causing this problem while I am using `express-mysql-session`? How do I need to rewrite my `supertest` call to make the test work again?

If this is not possible with `supertest`, is there another way to write this test?